# ParseQuery having constraints related to time?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am using Parse as a back end to an Android Application.
Since Parse don't directly offer any DataType to store time values(each row of the record need to be associated with a time) ,i am storing the values in a String format(HH:mm).

Further i need to use those values in ParseQuery.

e.g i want to get those record which have that concerned value with in next one hour to the current time.

Once i have the String value,no doubt i can extract the values easily to match things but i want to do that in the Query itself.I also thought to write cloud function for that which extract String values and send back the result.

So am i missing anything ? or is there any other standard approach to used Time/Date in ParseQuery ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse.com supports date objects, and you can query on dates using greaterThan or lessThan.
Using strings does not seem to be a good way of handling this.

If I understand your use case correctly, you need to query for records that have a date property greaterThan the current time and lessThan the current time + 1 hour.

I am an iOS developer, so my code example will be in Objective-C. It should be straightforward to translate it to Android, though:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Yourclass"];
[query whereKey:@"yourdatefield" greaterThan:cutoffLower]; // The current time
[query whereKey:@"yourdatefield" lessThan:cutoffUpper]; // The time + 1 hour
result = [query findObjects:&error]; // Or preferably findObjectsInBackground...
```

Let me know if there is anything I've misunderstood, and I will try to explain further.

Comment: You got it very correctly.What is the exact format of the Date type ? is it similar to java Date ? I mean can it work with only HH:mm format ? and please one more question ,how to set multiple constraints in a single parse Query (i want to match two different values) ,for that will i have to use AND construct . Anyways Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You just add constraints like in the example above, only they are for different fields. You could also say [query whereKey:@"usertype" equalTo:@"admin"] and parse would infer the "AND" behind the scene.

Comment: In regard to datatypes, they are listed here: https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide#objects-types (you should read the entire android guide, as it will probably answer many questions you have (or will have in the following weeks) :-)

Comment: The format is not really relevant to the handling of the date, as any date object will internally be translated to a standard format (epoch time, most likely), and the HH:mm is only for visual representation. But you can definitely use formats like that in Java to set the time, which will then be translated to millisecs since 1970 when used.

Comment: You answered everything very well .Thanks a lot !:)

Comment: Glad to have helped. Good luck with your app :-)